# How to create custom function in excel add-in using office JS in already existing react project

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am new to a **custom function**. I already have a react project. I want to use one custom function in that project. I have read the document about it. It has two options **either** you can create a **react js** project or you can create **custom function** project.

can anyone guide me on "how to create a custom function in react project"?

Answer (score 2):

Yadav, here is one option:

1. Generate a new add-in project using the yo office "Excel Custom Functions using a Shared Runtime" template.
2. Compare the following files with what you already have in your add-in project to identify the changes you need to make to add custom functions to your project: `manifest.xaml`, `package.json`, `webpack.config.js`.
3. Copy new files that identified in step 2 from the project you made in step 1 to your add-in project.
4. Make the changes identified in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

Office add-ins that combine two kind of features - custom functions and, for example, react web app are run all of its code in a single `shared runtime`. A `shared runtime` isn't a type of runtime. It refers to a browser-type runtime that's being shared by features of the add-in that would otherwise each have their own runtime. Specifically, you have the option of configuring the add-in's task pane and function commands to share a runtime. In an Excel add-in, you can configure custom functions to share the runtime of a task pane or function command or both. When you do this, the custom functions are running in a browser-type runtime, instead of a JavaScript-only runtime as it otherwise would.

See [Configure your add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) for information about the benefits and limitations of sharing runtimes and instructions for configuring the add-in to use a shared runtime. In brief, the JavaScript-only runtime uses less memory and starts up faster, but has fewer features.